# Huge table Excel

Tags: excel, csv

Good afternoon,

I have an excel table with 600k rows, every row include name,address,postcode,phone numbers.

And another file, a list of 27 million phone numbers.

What is the best option to remove every row from the first table if the phone number is included in the other file? Thank you very much!

Comment: Google the formula (VLOOKUP) to see how you might use it to accomplish what you need to do

Comment: not sure, but is there a limit to the number of rows excel can handle?

Comment: As far as I know, the maximum amount of rows in an Excel file is about 1048576, so I imagine the 27 million phone numbers are not stored in Excel, but in another format? I'd personally go for an application which is more suited for handling such big tables, like Access.

Comment: What is the nature of this 'other file'? Text file, CSV, or what?? As Excel basic app can only take 1M rows, I'm going to assume you have a NON-Excel file containing these 27M numbers. Probably a job for Power Query/Power Pivot, or a DB application that can do the reverse direction lookup and create back the Excel table in downsized form. I see the CSV tag, now so that means you have a CSV. Try PowerQuery/PowerPivot. I've never stretched it past 5M records, but I guess 27M should be fine.

Comment: Someone suggesting 122M rows for Power Pivot - http://www.microsofttrends.com/2014/02/09/how-much-data-can-powerpivot-really-manage-how-about-122-million-records/

Comment: Some one suggesting 400M rows for PowerPivot - http://powerpivotfaq.com/Lists/TGPPF/DispForm.aspx?ID=150

Comment: In any scenario - Excel is not the tool for this kind of data comparison. You can use OLEDB to query the other file with the phone numbers, but in that case you might as well be using a fully-fledged RDBMS

Comment: This is a classic case of trying to use Excel as a tool for something it was never designed to do. Excel isn't a database.